# Taylor series of twice continuously differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion, gradient-descent

Let $f$ be a twice continuously differentiable function with $d(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ be a descent direction such that $f'(x)d(x) < 0$. Use the Taylor series expansion to show that there exists $\epsilon_{0} > 0$ such that

$$ f(x + \epsilon d(x)) \leq f(x),  $$
for all $0 \leq \epsilon \leq \epsilon_{0}.$

The Taylor expansion is

$$ f(x + \epsilon d(x)) = f(x) + \epsilon f'(x) d(x) + \frac{\epsilon^2 d(x)^2}{2} f''(x). $$

I think that the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity can be used to solve this but I do not know how. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: This is false, since we can have $f'(x) = 0$ with $x$ being a global min. It is true though if $f'(x)d(x) < 0$. Without loss of generality, you can assume $d(x) = 1$.

Comment: @Mason How can i assume that $d(x) = 1$ without loss of generality ?

Comment: Note that $\lim_{ \epsilon \downarrow 0} { f(x+\epsilon d) - f(x) \over \epsilon} = f'(x) d < 0$. $f$ just needs to be differentiable at $x$, no need for $C^2$.

Comment: @endeavor It may be easier formally to leave it as it is. I'm mostly suggesting you assume that $d(x) = 1$ first because the problem becomes superficially simpler. The proof when $d(x) = -1$ or something else would just require small adjustment.

Comment: @copper.hat sorry for the question but can you give me a bit more details into your approach ?

Comment: It's just the definition of the derivative (or the chain rule, if you prefer). I find the language of descent direction utterly confusing when we're working with a single-variable function.

Comment: Choose $E>0$ in the limit so that for $0< \epsilon<E$ you have ${ f(x+\epsilon d) - f(x) \over \epsilon} < {1 \over 2} f'(x)d$.